# I need to combine these two formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, vlookup

I need to combine the following

=IF(B2="SUSP","Suspended",A2) and =VLOOKUP(A2,Lookup!AB:AC,2,0)

explanation: If SUSP isn't found in cell B2 then match value from column AB in 'lookup' tab and then return the value from AC in the 'lookup' tab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel allows the "Nesting" of formula, so just put the VLOOKUP in the False position.  That way when it does not equal "SUSP" it will run the VLOOKUP:

```
=IF(B2="SUSP","Suspended",VLOOKUP(A2,Lookup!AB:AC,2,0))
```

If `B2` does eqaul "SUSP" the IF will not even run the VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, Lookup!AB:AC, 2, 0) = "SUSP", "Suspended", A2)
```

Comment: [I believe you have it backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74197079/i-need-to-combine-these-two-formulas#comment131000006_74197079).